# how to send Push Notification from server side using Multicast

Tags: c#, android, asp.net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace AndroidPushNOtifcation
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SendCommandToAndroidPhone("APA91bHTWs7e0t57Y3ymbM2VVZakZ7vUzmXa8BJZdGAr06HUV5mBMbgorZOKlAQsMCmlXqXh1rt9IugPqi6eZ6cwfvZR_oY2YM9YzQnR45jXOrR5gK4U8oObnDjnObJ6d0PGMDX1MqFj_ey6_HKOXjty28T4H6YY7Q", "Second Test");
        }


        public string SendCommandToAndroidPhone(String deviceID, string Mesaj)
        {
            String GoogleAppID = "AIzaSyCwElHkNZpY6P2RkIsbMQWxI1OgQnuv8_g";

            WebRequest tRequest;
            tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
            tRequest.Method = "post";
            tRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", GoogleAppID));

            String collaspeKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");

            String postData = string.Format("registration_id={0}&data.payload={1}&collapse_key={2}", deviceID, Mesaj, collaspeKey);

            Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            try
            {
                Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                dataStream.Close();

                WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

                dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

                StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

                String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

                tReader.Close();
                dataStream.Close();
                tResponse.Close();

                return "Android : " + sResponseFromServer;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "Android : " + ex.Message;
            }
        }


    }



}
```

This code is work fine for single device id But fail in Multicast send Notification please Help me how i will send Multicast Notification in android. i Have Tried Much and try find how to send multicast send Notification i found in Java code But Not in c# code please help me how i will change it Multicast.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're using plain-text HTTP instead of using JSON.

Google stated in their documentation (http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html) that by using plain-text HTTP you can only send to ONE device at a time.

You're option is to switch to JSON, there you can use an array of registration ids (up to 1000) in once call.

For Example:

```
{ "collapse_key": "score_update",
   "time_to_live": 108,
   "delay_while_idle": true,
   "data": {
       "score": "4 x 8",
       "time": "15:16.2342"
   },
   "registration_ids":["4", "8", "15", "16", "23", "42"]
}
```

Google docs: http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/gcm.html

Edit:
This is just an example, I didn't run it, it is from my memory. But you can get the idea:
(you can use http://json.codeplex.com/ for JSON convertion):

```
try
{
    IEnumerable<string> registrationdIds = new List<string>(){"reg1","reg2","reg3"....,"reg1000"};
    var webRequest = WebRequest.Create("GCMServerUrl");
    webRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, string.Format("Key={0}", "GCMApiKey"));
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    var requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();

    var message = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    var data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    var parameters = new NameValueCollection();

    var registrationIds = UserManagement.GetDefaultUserManagement().GetUserAndroidRegistrationIds();
    message.Add("registration_ids", registrationIds);
    data.Add("Field1", "This is Field1");
    data.Add("Field2", "This is Field2");
    message.Add("data", data);

    var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);

    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);
    requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    using (var response = webRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        Logger.DebugFormat("Sent a GCM message. Response was:{0}", response);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.ErrorFormat("Error occurred while sending GCM notification. Ex: {0}", ex);
}
```

Comment: can u please Edit my code for sending Upto 1000 registration id sending Notification